# in array values are are not getting insert or push

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have some html with input datalist with comman name attributes I wanted to store all data from input array but it is not stored. I have tried jQuery push(). But it is only storing first value. 

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-childage">
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist id="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist id="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist id="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist id="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

**jQuery I used**

```
var childagearray = [];
$('#div-childage').each(function() {
    childagearray.push($("input[name='childage']").val());
});
var childage = JSON.stringify(childagearray);
```

**output want in Integer Array**

Comment: That is because `childage` is an ID. ID's can only appear once on a page

Comment: childage is the div id wait let me do some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should give each datalist an unique `id` or it will always return the first `id`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var childagearray = [];
  $('input').each(function() {
    childagearray.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(childagearray)
  var childage = JSON.stringify(childagearray);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="childage">
  <input list="childage1" name="childage">
  <datalist id="childage1">
        <option value="0" selected>
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
  <input list="childage2" name="childage">
  <datalist id="childage2">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
  <input list="childage3" name="childage">
  <datalist id="childage3">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
  <input list="childage4" name="childage">
  <datalist id="childage4">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
</div>

<button>Push data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute which is invalid. Id must be unique to a document. To group elements, convert the id to classes:

```
<div id="childage-container">
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist class="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist class="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist class="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
    <input list="childage" name="childage"> 
    <datalist class="childage">
        <option value="0">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

From there you can use `map()` to create the array you need:

```
var childagearray = $('.childage').map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
var childage = JSON.stringify(childagearray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var childagearray = [];
$('#div-childage').find('input[name="childage"]').each(function() {
    childagearray.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(childagearray);
var childage = JSON.stringify(childagearray);
```